# How to match a word between single but not double brackets without look-around?

Tags: regex, rust

The Rust [`Regex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html) crate has no look-around so I cannot use negative look-behind for `{` and a negative look-ahead for `}`.

I tried:

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let exp = Regex::new("(?:[^{]|^)\\{([^{}]*)\\}").unwrap();
    let text = "{this} is a match, {{escaped}} is not, but {these}{also} are.";

    for capture in exp.captures_iter(text) {
        println!("{}", &capture[1]);
    }
    // expected result: "this", "these", "also"
}
```

This does not catch `"also"` because the matches do not overlap. Is there a way to do so without look-around?

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're trying to match `{this}`, `{these}`, and `{also}`, but **not** `{{escaped}}`?

Comment: @ctwheels Yes, I will edit my question

Comment: [You may use alternation: `{{.*?}}|\{([^{}]*)\}` and use captured group #1 as you're already using.](https://regex101.com/r/tIUycK/1)

Comment: Remove last `}` in your regex `(?:[^{]|^)\\{([^{}]+)`

Comment: You can use the [`fancy_regex`](https://docs.rs/fancy-regex/0.1.0/fancy_regex/) crate for lookarounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the discard technique and use a pattern like this:

```
{{|}}|{([^}]+)}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/elzoca/2)**

[image]

Or simpler to read if you need to match alphanumeric and underscore

```
{{|}}|{(\w+)}
```

---

In your code, you must now check if there is matching group 1:

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let exp = Regex::new(r"\{\{|\}\}|\{([^}]+)\}").unwrap();
    let text = "{this} is a match, {{escaped}} is not, but {these}{also} are.";

    for capture in exp.captures_iter(text) {
        if let Some(matched) = capture.get(1) {
            println!("{}", matched.as_str());
        }
    }
    // printed: "this", "these", "also"
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't know one could do this "discard technique", thanks.